# Why does the mdentropy tutorial give an error in scikit-learn/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, information-theory

Upon doing a tutorial on mutual information in mdentropy package, I am getting the following error:

```
File "/home/midhun/scikit-learn/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 994, in fit_predict
return self.fit(X, sample_weight=sample_weight).labels_
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'
```

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Show the full stack trace of error.

Answer (score 0):

The sample_weight parameter was added to KMeans and a number of other sklearn estimators back in [version 0.20.0](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#highlights):

> Beyond this, we have added sample_weight support to several estimators
>   (including KMeans, BayesianRidge and KernelDensity) and improved
>   stopping criteria in others (including MLPRegressor,
>   GradientBoostingRegressor and SGDRegressor).

I suspect that your version of sklearn is before 0.20.0. Take a look at the documentation for the [previous stable version, 0.19.2](http://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit.) You can see that `fit()` did not have a `sample_weight` parameter. You can solve your problem by updating your sklearn to the latest version, or at least 0.20.0.

Comment: Again I Updated to 0.21.dev0 version of sklearn. It is giving me the same error. numpy 1.21.1,  scipy 1.1.0, Cython: 0.28.5 and pandas: 0.23.4 are installed in my system.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to generate the error and a full stacktrace of the error in question? Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Though I updated sklearn, the files of the previous version were not deleted from the installed folder. I deleted all those files and freshly installed sklearn 0.20.0 It works now, ss you answered.

Comment: Glad I could help! Consider [upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)